# BigQuery Alert for finding who is scanning more bytes

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Scanned Bytes Billed alert in Google BigQuery. But I'm not able to identify the user and the query which is causing the alert to be generated. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the detail at the job level.  You could also remove the job_id from the select and aggregate bytes billed by user_email.

```
select job_id, user_email, total_bytes_billed
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
where job_id = 'job_id#'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for more of a just in time alert. The moment someone runs a query that is scanning bytes being billed, I should get an alert with the user name, query etc.

Comment: Please update your question with what you currently have and sample output.